# Can not getting complete stdout using node.js

Tags: node.js, electron

i am using following code in my app:

```
var path = app.getAppPath();
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const child = exec(`"${path}\\PC-BASIC\\a.bat"`, []);
var stdout = '';
var stderr = '';
child.stdout.on('data', function(buf) {
  //console.log('[STR] stdout "%s"', String(buf));
  stdout += buf;
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(buf) {
  //console.log('[STR] stderr "%s"', String(buf));
  stderr += buf;
});
child.on('close', function(code) {
  console.log('[END] code', code);
  console.log('[END] stdout "%s"', stdout);
  console.log('[END] stderr "%s"', stderr);
});
```

when i run a.bat from command line (dos). i get the exact result. but when i run it from my electron app i writes following on console:

```
 [END] code 0
 [END] stdout "
 D:\Documents\Nauman Umer\New folder\electron-quick-start>"C:\Program Files (x86)\PC-BASIC\pcbasic.com" --load="ART.BAS" --convert=A
 "
 [END] stderr ""
```

but expected is:

```
 [END] code 0
 [END] stdout "
 D:\Documents\Nauman Umer\New folder\electron-quick-start>"C:\Program Files (x86)\PC-BASIC\pcbasic.com" --load="ART.BAS" --convert=A
 [FILE TEXT AS IN OUTPUT OF BAT]
 "
 [END] stderr ""
```

i also tried to execute `pcbasic` directly from command line instead of from app but the results are same.

Comment: Are you sure the program prints to stdout. Not all programs on Windows print to stdout. Some directly call the console API to print their output.

Comment: its an python program and using `sys.stdout.write()` for writing to console.

Answer (score 1):

If the child process uses `GetConsoleMode` to detect whether it runs in a console, try calling it using `spawn()` rather than `exec()` in line 3 of your code.

`child_process.exec()` launches a console, and then launches the program inside that console - so the child process called by `a.bat` sees a console and may use the console API, as suggested by @slebetman .

`child_process.spawn()` launches the program directly and makes its stdout available through a pipe, so the child process should not see a console (and cannot use the console API).

See here for details: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: I am using this code ```const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  const ls = spawn("D:\\Documents\\Nauman Umer\\New folder\\electron-quick-start\\PC-BASIC\\a.bat", []);

  ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  ls.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });``` but note getting any thing

Comment: the output is ```stdout:
D:\Documents\Nauman Umer\New folder\electron-quick-start>"D:\Documents\Nauman Umer\New folder\electron-quick-start\PC-BASIC\pcbasic.com" --load="ART.BAS" --convert=A

child process exited with code 0```